# primefaces gmap search center

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I search for a place the map is updated.But the centering value does not get updated.Any help would be great.

/* The xhtml is given below */

```
<h:outputLabel value="Search Location :" for="acSimple" />
<p:autoComplete id="acSimple" minQueryLength="0" value="#{sampleMapProducer.searchString}" forceSelection="true" completeMethod="#{sampleMapProducer.complete}">
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="gmap_loc" process="#{sampleMapProducer.searchCenter}" />
    <p:ajax process="@this" update="gmap_loc" />
</p:autoComplete>
<p:outputPanel id="gmapPanel" autoUpdate="true">
    <p:gmap center="#{sampleMapProducer.searchCenter}" zoom="6" type="ROADMAP" style="width:100%;height:600px" model="#{sampleMapProducer.mapBySearch}" id="gmap_loc"></p:gmap>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Bean Code for the map:

```
private void clearMap (MapModel map)
{
    for (Marker marker : map.getMarkers()) {
        marker.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

/* Get map for searching */

```
 public MapModel getMapBySearch () 
 {
    clearMap(mapBySearch);
    for (Marker markerIterator : markersList)
    {
        if (searchString == null || searchString.trim().equals(""))
        {
            mapBySearch.addOverlay(markerForLocation(markerIterator,BLUE_DOT));
        }
        else
        {
          if (markerIterator.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase()))
            {
                mapBySearch.addOverlay(markerForLocation(markerIterator,BLUE_DOT));
            }
        }
    }
    return mapBySearch;
}
```

/* Auto complete String */

```
public List<String> complete ( String searchString) 
{
    List<String> suggestedStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String locationName : LOCATION_NAMES)
    {
        if (locationName.toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase())) {
            suggestedStrings.add(locationName);
        }
    }
    this.searchString = searchString;
    return suggestedStrings;
}
```

/* get location center */

```
public String getLocationCenter () 
{ 
    String center = "39,-98"; 
    for (LocationGeocodeBean geoCode : GEO_CODES) 
    { 
        if (geoCode.getId().equals(selectedLocationId())) 
        { 
            if ((geoCode.getLatitude() != 0) && (geoCode.getLongitude() != 0)) 
            { 
                center = String.format("%s,%s", geoCode.getLatitude(),geoCode.getLongitude()); } 
                return center; 
            } 
        } 

    }
    return center; 
}
```

Comment: Can you also post your backing bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i don't understand your code completely so i created a simple example. It puts some markers on the map and when you click the map the map centers to the marker. You can make use of callback parameters. So when you click or select something in your form you send back a parameter and catch this in JavaScript and then update your map. Try the following example:

Bean:

```
public class MapBean
{
    private MapModel advancedModel;

    public MapBean()
    {   
    advancedModel = new DefaultMapModel();

    LatLng coord1 = new LatLng(36.883707, 30.689216);
    LatLng coord2 = new LatLng(36.879703, 30.706707);
    LatLng coord3 = new LatLng(36.885233, 30.702323);

    advancedModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord1));
    advancedModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord2));
    advancedModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord3));

    }

    public MapModel getAdvancedModel()
    {

    return advancedModel;
    }

    public void onMarkerSelect(OverlaySelectEvent event)
    {   
    Marker marker = (Marker) event.getOverlay();
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();        
        context.addCallbackParam("lat", marker.getLatlng().getLat()); 
        context.addCallbackParam("lng", marker.getLatlng().getLng());        
    }

}
```

And the .xhtml

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:gmap center="36.890257,30.707417" zoom="13" type="HYBRID" model="#{mapBean.advancedModel}" style="width:600px;height:400px" id="maps" widgetVar="map" onPointClick="pointClick(event)">
        <p:ajax event="overlaySelect" listener="#{mapBean.onMarkerSelect}" oncomplete="handleComplete(xhr, status, args)"/>
    </p:gmap>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        function handleComplete(xhr, status, args) 
        {  
            //Create center point from callback params
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(args.lat , args.lng);
            //Get de google map from your widget now you can use the googlemap api
            var gmap = map.getMap();
            gmap.setCenter(latlng);                   
        }   
    </script>  
</h:form>
```